# How to post nested json in restassured

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Below is the code I am using

```
JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
requestParams.put("something", "something value");
requestParams.put("another.child", "child value");
```

This is how the api needs to be posted

```
{

   "something":"something value",
   "another": {
   "child": "child value"
   }
}
```

I get an error stating that the

> The another.child field is required.

How do I go about posting this via restAssured? The other APIs do not require posting with nesting work so I'm assuming that's why it's failing.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `another` as Json object within the main Json object.

```
JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
requestParams.put("something", "something value");

JSONObject anotherObject = new JSONObject();
anotherObject.put("child", "child value");

requestParams.put("another", anotherObject);

System.out.println(requestParams.toString());
```

This will print;

```
{"another":{"child":"child value"},"something":"something value"}
```

To pass this Json object to Rest Assured POST method;

```
    RestAssured.baseURI="base_url";

    RestAssured.given()
            .when()
            .post(requestParams.toString());
```

Required imports;

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
```

Comment: Thank you . I had to send something like    changeDetails" : {
 "requirement" : "https://jira"
 } So , I used   changeDetailsObject.put("requirement", "https://jira");

   jsonPayloadBody.put("changeDetails", changeDetailsObject); . I upvoted this answer and question.